# Filtering JSON by date with JLinq

Tags: javascript, json

I am using [JLinq](http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq) for filtering JSON data. Filtering by date is not working for me. I tried invoking methods but its same.

Here is my code snippet.

```
    //This works
    jlinq.from(myData)
                 .select(function(rec) {
                      return {
                           title:rec.title,
                           pubDate:rec.pubDate
                          }
                      });
```

This is the data returned by the above code.

```
    // And returned this data
    myData = [
        {pubDate: "2012-06-19T10:42:59.000Z",
        title: "How caching matters in JS?" },
        {pubDate: "2012-06-18T14:39:25.000Z",
        title: "Globbing in scripting languages"}
        {pubDate: "2012-06-14T17:50:22.000Z",
        title: "Inspecting Objects in Scripting"}
    ]
```

Its not working when I try to filter by date. Greater than or less than.

**EDITED**

```
    //Filter by pubDate
    jlinq.from(myData)
               .greater(new Date("pubDate"), new Date("2010-02-13T19:03:17.000Z"))
               .select();
```

This problem is specific to when comparing Date values. It returns empty array.

```
    //But Returns empty Array
    //[]
```

Comment: your dates are strings, so compare them to other strings... new Date(2000,3,5).toISOString()

Comment: I have to do this within the library, so I added date filter. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. I think the problem was that the library was assuming if the value is string compare **length** otherwise just compare **value1 > value2**.

I changed this code:

```
    //is the value greater than the argument
    { name:"greater", type:framework.command.query, 
        method:function(value) {
            return this.compare({
                array:function() { return this.value.length > value; },
                string:function() { return this.value.length > value; },
                other:function() { return this.value > value; }
            });
        }},
```

To this: by creating another filter called greaterDate, and converted the string to 'Date()'

```
    //is the value greaterDate than the argument
    { name:"greaterDate", type:framework.command.query, 
        method:function(value) {
            return this.compare({
                array:function() { return this.value.length > value; },
                string:function() { return new Date(this.value) > new Date(value); },
                other:function() {  return new Date(this.value) > new Date(value); }
            });
        }},
```

Maybe there is a better way, but I solved it with this for know.